# How do I set the background image size of a table cell in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

So far I have:

```
var imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(10, 10, cell.frame.width - 10, cell.frame.height - 10))
let image = UIImage(named: ImageNames[indexPath.row])
imageView.image = image
cell.backgroundView = imageView
```

This sets the background image, but my goal is to have 10 pixels worth of padding on either side. This is just filling the background of the cell with this image.

Comment: Then don't assign your image view as the background view. Define your image view with the frame you want and then add it to the existing background view, or content view (as per your needs).

Comment: @0x7fffffff Aren't I already defining it with the frame I want and then adding it to the existing background view?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I actually was able to fix my own problem. I just created the background view and then added a subview to it like this:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: cell.frame.width - 10, height: cell.frame.height - 10))
let image = UIImage(named: "Image Name")
imageView.image = image
cell.backgroundView = UIView()
cell.backgroundView!.addSubview(imageView)
```

This prevents anything from being covered up and achieves the effect I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(10, 10, cell.frame.width - 10, cell.frame.height - 10))
let image = UIImage(named: ImageNames[indexPath.row])
imageView.image = image
//Just add imageView as subview of cell
cell.addSubView(imageView)
cell.sendSubviewToBack(imageView)
```

Comment: This is covering up all of my existing items in the cell though.

Comment: sendbackSubView.Edited my answer